# Flip the numbers on bar plot, using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that I'm creating using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(flexbooks, aes(x=SchoolYear, y=Count,fill=Type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(data=flexbooks,aes(label=Count),vjust=-1,hjust=0.5)
p
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

I would like to flip the numbers here. The ones shown on top have to be at the bottom and vice-versa.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the legend:

```
p <- ggplot(flexbooks, aes(x=SchoolYear, y=Count,fill=Type)) +  
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     geom_text(data=flexbooks,aes(label=Count),vjust=-1,hjust=0.5) +
     guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```